# A second resize event is triggered after entering fullscreen on Android Chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I've encountered an issue after a recent Chrome update on Android where a window resize event occurs after entering fullscreen during the next interaction. For example, when I enter fullscreen in portrait orientation on my device, the screen height becomes 854 pixels, with the address bar being hidden. However, on the subsequent interaction, another resize event takes place. The address bar remains hidden, but the screen height is resized to approximately 806 pixels, which is halfway between its original height of 702 pixels. Has anyone else noticed this issue? If so, I would appreciate it if someone could share a potential fix. Thank you.

I don't believe that there is a way to fix this at the moment.

Comment: Could you explain what issue this is causing?, a potential fix might be using a different unit size like `dvw / dvh` etc.

Comment: This is causing a resize of my UI. Since the screen height is reduced a bit after this event. It's a WebGL app and not an HTML app. I don't understand why I get this new resize event on first interaction after entering fullscreen. Before the Chrome update there was no resize event after entering fullscreen. Also this happened only in portrait orientation.